# where can I find ml_utils.model gps? I've seen a few papers reference these dependencies but cannot find a ml_utils package with gp

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, gaussian-process

Does `ml_utils` package still exist with `.models.gp`?
I cannot find it but have seen it in 4+ papers now.

Found a pandas `ml_utils` documentation (https://github.com/KIC/pandas_ml_utils/blob/master/pandas_ml_utils/model/models.py) but don't see any GPs under models. Can someone please help me figure out what these papers are using? They all just say `from ml_utils.model import gp` and have `ml_utils` listed under there dependencies.